# Limpiar Spinbox a por defecto Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen dia, Estoy intentado que el Spinbox se limpie al numero por defecto automáticamente después de ciertos minutos. Es posible? Como lo agregaria a mi código ?, Muchas gracias!

```
s1 = Spinbox(ventana, from_=1,to=1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución más sencilla que he adaptado y que es lógica en otros programas que he hecho
usando controles giratorios (en adelante, Spinbox) es que el cuadro de entrada retome la función por el tiempo que le he puesto, es necesario primero usar la variable StringVar().

La solución es esperar el tiempo que usted establezca en milisegundos, cuando alcance ese tiempo, se cargara la función encargada de restablecer al valor predeterminado.

Código de ejemplo en su caso:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#Autor John Deb, código modificable. 24/02/21, nombre común the gamer :v

ventana= tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry('400x260')
ventana.geometry('+360+20')
ventana.resizable(0,0)
ventana.title('Restaurar valor automáticamente')

# Definir los widgets del programa como labels, controles entre otros...

SpinBoxVar = tk.StringVar()
SpinBoxVar.set("0")
s1 = tk.Spinbox(ventana, from_=1,to=1000, textvariable=SpinBoxVar)
s1.place(x=30, y=20)

#== Establecer el tiempo mediante la ventana inicial o el Toplevel, en este caso es "ventana" ==#

def resetValue():
    SpinBoxVar.set("1000") #Valor predeterminado que le asigne.

    resetDefaultValueLoad() # Reutiliza la función anterior para reiniciar contínuamente el conteo.

def resetDefaultValueLoad():
    ventana.after(5000, resetValue) #Puse 5 seg de espera para que luego cargue la función


resetDefaultValueLoad() #Reinicia el conteo cada 5 sec.

ventana.mainloop()
```